c++ write screenshot to memory and encoding to base64
I ask for your help. I have a task: take a screenshot of the screen, compress it into jpeg format, encode it in base64 and send it over the network.
I wrote a small test program that takes a screenshot of the screen. I use some function to compress the image. Then I use the Poco library to encode it into a base64 string. To check the correctness of the encoding, I save the encoded string to a file, just as I save the screenshot itself to a file. To make sure I get the correct screenshot and convert it to a base64 string correctly.
But I get an incorrect base64 string. It has some strange format. And I can’t convert it back into an image in any online decoder. Please help me understand how to correct my code so that I can get the correct base64 string.
I've got one more question. Is it possible to somehow get a JPEG image without using the rather large libJPEG library? I found one simple example - toojpeg
But I can't save an image using it. How can I use this library correctly?
I use Kubuntu 20.04,  Clion IDE, conan 1.62.
It is necessary to set up the project in the CLion IDE (cmake options):
-G Ninja -DAGENT_VERSION=1.5.0 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=external/cmake-helpers/toolchains/x86_64-linux-clang.cmake -DENABLE_DEBUG_MODE:BOOL=ON

Below I will give the code of the main program file main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <jpeglib.h>
#include <filesystem>

#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>
#include <fmt/os.h>

#include <Poco/Base64Encoder.h>

#include "DateTime.hpp"

int width;
int height;
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> image_buffer;

// function compress image data
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> process_scale_bilinear(XImage * image, int new_width, int new_height){
   std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> image_data;
   std::vector<unsigned char> image_data_row;
   float x_ratio = ((float) (width))/new_width;
   float y_ratio = ((float) (height))/new_height;
   unsigned long red_mask = image->red_mask;
   unsigned long green_mask = image->green_mask;
   unsigned long blue_mask = image->blue_mask;

   for (int new_y=0; new_y < new_height; new_y++) {
       for (int new_x=0; new_x < new_width; new_x++) {

           // x1, y1 is coordinates original pixel to take from original image
           // x2 is step to the right
           //y2 is step down
           int x_1 =  new_x * x_ratio;
           if (x_1 >= width) x_1 = width - 1; //becouse start pint is 0 and final is 1 less
           int y_1 =  new_y * y_ratio;
           if(y_1 >= height) y_1 = height - 1; //becouse start pint is 0 and final is 1 less
           int x_2 = x_1 + x_ratio;
           if (x_2 >= width) x_2 = width - 1;
           int y_2 = y_1 + y_ratio;
           if(y_2 >= height) y_2 = height - 1;
           float x_diff = (x_ratio * new_x) - x_1 ;
           float y_diff = (y_ratio * new_y) - y_1 ;

           // 4 point for bilineral function
           unsigned long q_1_1 = XGetPixel(image, x_1, y_1);
           unsigned long q_1_2 = XGetPixel(image, x_1, y_2);
           unsigned long q_2_1 = XGetPixel(image, x_2, y_1);
           unsigned long q_2_2 = XGetPixel(image, x_2, y_2);
           // blue element
           // Yb = Ab(1-w1)(1-h1) + Bb(w1)(1-h1) + Cb(h1)(1-w1) + Db(wh)
           float blue = (q_1_1 & blue_mask) * (1 - x_diff) * (1 - y_diff) + (q_1_2 & blue_mask) * (x_diff) * (1 - y_diff) +
                        (q_2_1 & blue_mask) * (y_diff) * (1 - x_diff) + (q_2_2 & blue_mask) * (x_diff * y_diff);

           // green element
           // Yg = Ag(1-w1)(1-h1) + Bg(w1)(1-h1) + Cg(h1)(1-w1) + Dg(wh)
           float green = ((q_1_1 & green_mask) >> 8) * (1-x_diff) * (1-y_diff) + ((q_1_2 & green_mask) >> 8) * (x_diff) * (1 - y_diff) +
                         ((q_2_1 & green_mask) >> 8) * (y_diff) * (1-x_diff) + ((q_2_2 & green_mask) >> 8) * (x_diff * y_diff);

           // red element
           // Yr = Ar(1-w1)(1-h1) + Br(w1)(1-h1) + Cr(h1)(1-w1) + Dr(wh)
           float red = ((q_1_1 & red_mask) >> 16) * (1 - x_diff) * (1 - y_diff) + ((q_1_2 & red_mask) >> 16) * (x_diff) * (1 - y_diff) +
                       ((q_2_1 & red_mask) >> 16) * (y_diff) * (1 - x_diff) + ((q_2_2 & red_mask) >> 16) * (x_diff * y_diff);

           image_data_row.push_back((int) red);
           image_data_row.push_back((int) green);
           image_data_row.push_back((int )blue);
       }
       image_data.push_back(image_data_row);
       image_data_row.clear();
   }
   // update width and height after resize
   width = new_width;
   height = new_height;
   return image_data;
};

bool save_to_jpeg(const char * path, int quality)
{
   FILE *fp = NULL;
   struct jpeg_compress_struct cinfo;
   struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
   JSAMPARRAY row;

   fp = fopen(path, "wb");
   if (!fp) {
       std::cout << "Failed to create file " << path << std::endl;
       return false;
   }
   cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
   jpeg_create_compress(&cinfo);
   jpeg_stdio_dest(&cinfo, fp);
   cinfo.image_width = width;
   cinfo.image_height = height;
   cinfo.input_components = 3;
   cinfo.in_color_space = JCS_RGB;
   jpeg_set_defaults(&cinfo);
   jpeg_set_quality (&cinfo, quality, TRUE);
   jpeg_start_compress(&cinfo, TRUE);
   for(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>::size_type i = 0; i != image_buffer.size(); i++) {
       row = (JSAMPARRAY) &image_buffer[i];
       jpeg_write_scanlines(&cinfo, row, 1);
   }
   jpeg_finish_compress(&cinfo);
   jpeg_destroy_compress(&cinfo);
   if (fp != NULL) fclose(fp);

   return true;
};

int main() {

   try {

       Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
       Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);

       XWindowAttributes attributes = {0};
       XGetWindowAttributes(display, root, &attributes);

       width  = attributes.width;
       height = attributes.height;

       XImage *image = XGetImage(display, root, 0, 0, width, height, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);

       std::cout << "got screenshot";

       image_buffer = process_scale_bilinear(image, 720, 480);

       std::filesystem::path data_root_path("/var/opt");
       auto data_dir_path   = data_root_path / "my_program" / "screenshots";
       std::string datetimeStr = helpers::DateTime::currentDateTime().to_string("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
       std::string fileNameImage = data_dir_path / fmt::format("lastscreenshot_{0}.jpeg",datetimeStr);
       std::string fileNameBase64 = data_dir_path / fmt::format("base64_{0}.txt",datetimeStr);

       if (save_to_jpeg(fileNameImage.c_str(), 75))
       {
           std::cout << "Successfully saved to file";
       }


       std::stringstream string_stream1;

       Poco::Base64Encoder encoder(string_stream1);
       encoder.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *> (image_buffer.data()),
                     static_cast<int64_t>          (image_buffer.size()));
       encoder.close();

       std::string base64String = fmt::format("{0}{1}", "data:image/jpeg;base64,", string_stream1.str());
       fmt::ostream fileBase64 = fmt::output_file(fileNameBase64.c_str(), fmt::file::WRONLY | fmt::file::CREATE);
       fileBase64.print("{0}", base64String);
   }
   catch (std::exception& exception)
   {
       std::cout << "Exception: " << std::string(exception.what());
   }

   return 0;
}


You can download the full code from this link - Google Drive
Below I will give an example of how I tried to use Toojpeg to save an image to a file and get some buffer to encode it in base64:
        // example use toojpeg
        std::vector<unsigned char> bufferCompress {};
        auto myOutput = [&](unsigned char oneByte) { bufferCompress.push_back(oneByte); };

        bool result = TooJpeg::writeJpeg(myOutput, image->data,
                                         width, height, true, 75, false);

        // save to file image and encoding to base64
        std::string fileNameImage2 = data_dir_path / fmt::format("lastscreenshot2_{0}.jpeg",datetimeStr);
        std::string fileNameBase642 = data_dir_path / fmt::format("base642_{0}.txt",datetimeStr);

        std::stringstream string_stream2;

        Poco::Base64Encoder encoder2(string_stream2);
        encoder2.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *> (bufferCompress.data()),
                      static_cast<int64_t>          (bufferCompress.size()));
        encoder2.close();

        // save image
        std::ofstream myFile(fileNameImage2, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
        myFile << bufferCompress.data();

        //save base64
        fmt::ostream fileBase642 = fmt::output_file(fileNameBase642.c_str(), fmt::file::WRONLY | fmt::file::CREATE);
        fileBase64.print("{0}", string_stream2.str());

but the file is not saved correctly. It cannot be opened as a picture. The resulting buffer (bufferCompress) is encoded into an image, but it is not compressed, weighs a lot, and when decoding online, everything turns out to be a gray stripe...

You are aware that your image_buffer.data does not give you any data -- just the vectors? Your reinterpret_cast, which is a very bad thing in C++, then hides this problem... but, of course, I don't know any of the libraries involved; I just don't think the base64 encoder can work with what you're giving it.

I thought so too. But how can I now convert the resulting data vector to base64?

Depends on what you need for the API. If you need one large chunk of bytes, then you have to loop over that data and construct that one large chunk of bytes. If, on the other hand, the base64 encoder can process multiple data chunks that you just send one after the other, you just need to loop over the outer vector and send the inner data to the base64 encoder.

can I ask you for a code example on how to do this so that it works correctly?

As I said, I'm not familiar with the libraries you are using, so most of what I'm saying is conjecture anyway. And, didn't you say your images aren't displayed either? Or is that just the base64? Because, again, your row = (JSAMPARRAY) &image_buffer[i]; looks mighty suspicious too, even more so since I don't know whether a JSAMPARRAY is actually a pointer to a vector... it generally seems you're just casting random things...

Also, come to think of it -- isn't your base64 supposed to contain the jpeg? If you really want to write your pixel data, something like for (const auto& row: image_buffer) { encoder2.write(row.data(), row.size()); } might already do the trick -- the base64 encoder seems to be able to get data in chunks, as suggested by the final close that you call on it -- you can probably just write data and call close when done.
